# Winforms: Multiple Dialogue forms from a loop

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog, multithreading

I have a requirement where in my application should show alert boxes (dialogue forms). The issue is that the latest alert should be shown first and on closing it the next one - and so on. So I decided to move the dialogue creation to separate threads so that they are not required to be closed for remaining code to execute.

I did something like below. but the issue is that they dont appear as dialogues(can move on to main form without closing them). So I decided to use `ShowDialog(IWin32Window)`
But it gives me cross thread operation invalid error.

How to handle this case?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                new Thread(new ThreadStart(ShowDialogue)).Start();
                Thread.Sleep(1500);
            }
        }


 private void ShowDialogue()
        {          
                FormDialogue fd = new FormDialogue(-1);
                fd.ShowDialog( ); 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fd.Show()` instead of `fd.ShowDialog()` if you want your main form to be available. No threads are needed.

Comment: _the issue is that they dont appear as dialogues_

Comment: @HenkHolterman *they are not required to be closed for remaining code to execute* dialogs will remaining code to execute

Answer (score 0):

it appears from your question that you wish the resulting "dialog stack" to be modal (view one dialog at a time, have to close them all to get back to the main form).

I would recommend against using the threads, but rather just run your loop with ShowDialog directly in it. For instance:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        FormDialogue fd = new FormDialogue(-1);
        fd.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

You will need to keep a list of the alerts you want an process them according to the priority you have stated above.

I, however, suspect that you will find that if there are very many alert dialogues, that your users won't like this approach very much, and you may find yourself going back to a single dialogue that shows all the alerts at once.

Another choice, is to send all of the alert information (in a list maybe) to a single dialogue and in that dialog have the OK button iterate through the list displaying the alert until done.

Either way should be pretty simple.